# jquery.hover() adds class and removes it immediatly

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover, mousehover

I cannot show any pen, I can just describe the bug. This is my javascript:

```
$(".vetrina-deluxe-info-container-front").hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.js-in-viewport-hook').addClass("in-viewport");
}, function() {
  $(this).closest('.js-in-viewport-hook').removeClass("in-viewport");
});
```

On the first `.hover()` on any of these elements, the class is added and immediately removed. From the second time I hover everything works fine.

I've also tried this code:

```
$(".vetrina-deluxe-info-container-front").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.js-in-viewport-hook').addClass("in-viewport");
});

$(".vetrina-deluxe-info-container-front").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).closest('.js-in-viewport-hook').removeClass("in-viewport");
});
```

It has the exact same behavior. I have also tried to change the `.hover()` div to see if anything changes but no. Any ideas or workaround?

Comment: We can't diagnose a problem that you can't reproduce for us. You don't have to show a full Codepen, just a basic snippet that shows the behaviour will be enough.

Comment: Sounds like your `in-viewport` class changes something (like position or sizes) so pointer happens to be not over `.vetrina-deluxe` container anymore every time it hovers over

Comment: If it satisfies the requirements, just use a css `:hover` rule. I suspect that `closest` does not match the correct element every time.

Comment: @Andrey  that's why i tried to change the $(div) but I got still the same error. cannot do a fiddle because the scenario is very complex + this only happens ONCE. that's the weird part

Comment: It's actually none of our concern if it's complex. Your behaviour comes from what you have, if you can't reproduce for us or describe your situation, we can't answer you. As simple as that. It's like going to the doctor and tell him "cure me, but i won't tell you any detail about my problem"

Answer (score 0):

I've tried in diferents elements.

```js
    $('.test').mouseover(function(e){
        console.log('ON');
        $(this).removeClass('blue');
        $(this).addClass('red');
    }).mouseout(function(e){
               $(this).removeClass('red');
       console.log('OUT');
       $(this).addClass('blue');
    });
    $('#test').mouseenter(function(e){
        console.log('IN');
        $(this).removeClass('red');
        $(this).addClass('yellow');
    }).mouseleave(function(e){
       $(this).removeClass('yellow');
                  $(this).removeClass('yellow');
       console.log('OUT');
       $(this).addClass('red');
    });
```

```css
.test{
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    }
    
    .yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
    }
    .red{
    background-color: red;
    }
    
    .blue{
    background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <div class="test yellow">
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>
</html>
```

Your code will be like:

```
$(".vetrina-deluxe-info-container-front").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).closest('.js-in-viewport-hook').addClass("in-viewport");
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).closest('.js-in-viewport-hook').removeClass("in-viewport");
});
```

Comment: this is happening in your example as well, on a random basis. while leaving the div sometimes i get OUT ON instead of just OUT.

Comment: Strange, this doesn't  happenned here. Maybe because I used mouseleave and mouseout on this exemple. Use just one of them.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this code:

```
$(".vetrina-deluxe-info-container-front").hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.js-in-viewport-hook').toggleClass("in-viewport");
});
```

Comment: Please, explain why do you think that this code will solve the OP problem. [answer]

Answer (score -1):

```
    please check this i have added class on hover then i remove the class name when not hovered
        <p>hover me.</p>
 <script>
   $("p").hover(function(){
       $(this).css({"color":"blue"}).addClass('color-blue');
    }, function(){
       $("p").css({"color":"red"}).removeClass('color-blue');
    });
 </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gapqc5wb/

Comment: i don't need to remove it after 3s. i need to remove it when it's not hovering the div

Comment: fixed please check